# Создать класс по его имени в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть меню, каждому элементу прописан id: string, совпадающий с названием класса, соответствующим этому пункту меню.
Каким образом можно подключить и создать класс в обработчике меню по указанному имени класса?

Comment: Покажи код ! Не понятно что именно требуется сделать ...

Comment: @santavital, eсли коротко, то по имени класса нужно создать react компонент, т.е. должно быть что-то типа такого this.cont = React.createElement(compName), где compName - строковое название компонента. Имена компонентов хранятся отдельно в json, делать мэпинг типов с его названием не хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно создать компонентны из массива например так:

```
const menu = [
  { id: 1, name: "abc" },
  { id: 2, name: "def" },
  { id: 3, name: "ghi" },
];

const MenuItem = ({ name }) => <div>{name}</div>;
```

далее в рендере:

```
 {menu.map((e) => (
      <MenuItem key={e.id} {...e} />
  ))}
```